# clearing browser history using jquery/javascript

Tags: browser, browser-history

I am having an application where there will be lots of ajax calls and jquery load functions etc.I found that dynamic content is not loaded correctly every time i open the page due to browser history,if i delete the history and refresh the page its working fine.now

1. is there any way to clean up the history of the browser?(is this method correct?)
2. Can i prevent the page from being cached????using any jquery code.so that my application wont  be stored in browsers history.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set ***cache*** to ***false*** in your jquery ajax settings

see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: while testing a webpage,I am not able to see the changes i made when i refresh the page.if i delete the browsers history ,clear everything,then refresh its working fine,Its not regarding the ajx calls,or about dynamic data,its with applying styles,using jquery.